# Python: Compare lines in a CSV and append portions of the line to earlier rows

Tags: python, csv

I've got a CSV file that lists multiple records for a single transaction. Each transaction has an ID that might appear in anywhere from two to 16 rows. Each row has a field (info) unique to that row. A simplified data set is below. I'm trying to figure out how to read the first line of the CSV into a new file, then check the second line. If the two [0] fields match, I'll grab the fields I need and append them into the first line, then check the next line's [0]. If the [0] fields don't match, it needs to be a new line in the news file, and I then start checking [0] fields against that line's [0] value.

Input data

```
0987, A, info1, apple
0987, A, info2, apple
0987, B, info3, apple
0987, B, info4, apple
0987, B, info5, apple
0765, A, info6, orange
0765, A, info7, orange
0765, B, info8, orange
0589, A, info9, apple
0589, B, info10, apple
```

What I need:

```
0987, info1, info2, apple, info3, info4, info5
0765, info6, info7, orange, info8
0589, info9, apple, info10
```

I'd also be OK with a solution that just appended the related rows on the end of the first one because I know how I could then go through and slice out the fields I need into a new file. It's making sure I get the right rows combined that has me stumped - which probably means it's stupidly easy and I've just been staring at this for too long.

Comment: Use a dictionary, read csv files into arrays, use first index values in that input array as dictionary keys, dictionary values will be arrays containing all keywords found under that key. You haven't put up any code.. can't help you further thanks

Comment: build dictionary, with keys being numbers, and values list (or set if you want unique items), to which you append/add 3rd and 4th element from your csv. `collections.defauldict` might help you avoid `keyError`.

Comment: Thanks - that got me pointed in the right direction. I knew it would be something simple I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach in my opinion is to use `defaultdict(set)`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

info = defaultdict(set)
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        name, _, *props = line.split()
        info[name].update(props)

for k in info:
    print(k, info[k])
```

Alternatively, instead of `name, _, *props = line.split()`, you could use:

```
l = line.split()
name, props = l[0], l[2:]
```

For Python 2.

Comment: Syntax Error on 'name, _, *props = line.split()'

Comment: Then you're probably using python 2. This was run using python 3.